# Radius of Convergence

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

Is the radius of convergence of 
$$\frac{n(x+3)^n}{4^n}$$
equals 4?

I got $|x+3|\lt 4$ as the final result. How do you know, what is the radius from here?

Answer (score 3):

The *radius of convergence* of 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-a)^n\tag{1}
$$
is the number $R$ such that (1) converges for $\lvert x-a\rvert<R$ and diverges for $\lvert x-a\rvert>R$. In our case, we can apply the Ratio Test to the power series
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{4^n}(x+3)^n\tag{2}
$$ 
Doing so gives
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert\frac{\frac{n+1}{4^{n+1}}(x+3)^{n+1}}{\frac{n}{4^n}(x+3)^n}\right\rvert
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n+1}{n}\frac{4^n}{4^{n+1}}\left\lvert\frac{(x+3)^{n+1}}{(x+3)^n}\right\rvert 
= \frac{1}{4}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{n}\left\lvert x+3\right\rvert
=\frac{1}{4}\left\lvert x+3\right\rvert
$$
It follows that (2) converges when
$$
\frac{1}{4}\left\lvert x+3\right\rvert<1
$$
and diverges when
$$
\frac{1}{4}\left\lvert x+3\right\rvert>1
$$
Equivalently, (2) converges when 
$$
\left\lvert x+3\right\rvert<4
$$
and diverges when
$$
\left\lvert x+3\right\rvert>4
$$
Thus the radius of convergence of (2) is $R=4$.

Comment: Nice answer and explanation. +1

Comment: @Brian Great answer and explanation. This may seem blatantly obvious but why does
it follow that $$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{4^n}(x+3)^n
$$  converges when
$$
\frac{1}{4}\left\lvert x+3\right\rvert<1
$$                                                                                                            It's not clear to me why $$
\frac{1}{4}\left\lvert x+3\right\rvert<1
$$ for convergence to take place. Could you please explain in simple English why this is so?

Comment: @BLAZE Are you familiar with the ratio test?

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick Yes i am

Answer (score 1):

I would say that
the radius of convergence is 4
centered at -3.

Since the center of convergence
is usually zero,
I think that it is
important to state
when some other center is used.

Answer (score 1):

You got $ |x+3| < 4 $ as the final result.

$$|x-a| < R$$ where $a$ is the center of convergence and $R$ is the radius.

The inequality you obtained is in the form of the inequality above. $R$ is the radius of convergence. Comparing the two statements, $R = 4$.